# How to send and retrieve data from web method using JQuery Ajax Call?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a text box and a button next to it. I want to send the content of textbox through Jquery ajax call to webmethod and get back the upper case value of the same and display that in alert. So far i have this code but its not working.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function CallWM()
    {          

        var name = $('#name').val();         


        RealCallWM(name);


    }
    function RealCallWM(name) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'Register.aspx/UpperWM',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: { name: JSON.stringify(name) },
            success: OnSuccess(response),
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        })
    };
```

HTML:

```
  Name:    <input id="name" type="text" /> 
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="CallWM();"/></div>
    </form>
```

WEB METHOD:

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static string UpperWM(string name )
        {
            var msg=name.ToUpper();
            return (msg);
        }
```

Comment: what is the console error message you getting?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined

Comment: ok, as Darin mentioned, use JSON.stringify(name)

Comment: @Delphian i made changes as suggested by Darin but  i am getting console error "Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined "

Comment: what is the use of "msg" in function "CallWM", and you are not passing the value while calling

Comment: I was passing a value earlier, forgot to remove it. But i am getting this error even after removing msg from CallWM

Comment: I have updated my code in the question

Comment: @George Stocker - why is this marked as a duplicate, at least in relation to the linked answer? While it doesn't say so outright, isn't this Web Forms (I say this due to .aspx and the reliance on WebMethods)? Or is it duplicate because the answer is specific to the JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment I understood your issue not yet resolved, so just try this

```
    function RealCallWM(name) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/UpperWM",
            data: JSON.stringify({ name: $('#name').val() }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function (data, status) {
                console.log("CallWM");
                alert(data.d);
            },               
            failure: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Same error Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined 
I guess we are looking for problem at he wrong place. I know it must be something silly, i am trying to figure out whats causing this error.

Answer (score 4):

Replace:

```
data: '{name: ' + name + '}',
```

with:

```
data: { name: JSON.stringify(name) },
```

to ensure proper encoding. Right now you are sending the following payload:

```
{name:'some value'}
```

which is obviously an invalid JSON payload. In JSON everything should be double quoted:

```
{"name":"some value"}
```

That's the reason why you should absolutely never be building JSON manually with some string concatenations but using the built-in methods for that (`JSON.stringify`).

Side note: I am not sure that there's a callback called `failure` that the `$.ajax` method understands. So:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Register.aspx/UpperWM',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: { name: JSON.stringify(name) },
    success: OnSuccess(response),
    error: function (response) {                        
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

Also notice that in your error callback I have removed the `response.d` property as if there's an exception in your web method chances are that the server won't return any JSON at all.

Comment: Just for further edification, see [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: Darin is correct, there is no `failure` callback for the `jQuery.ajax()` method.

Comment: SOrry for responding late, i made the changes but i am getting the console error "ncaught ReferenceError: CallWM is not defined"

Comment: Where is this javascript code written? Is it in a separate javascript file? Did you reference this file in your WebForm? Also you must reference it before the button. Also since you are using jQuery don't forget to reference that as well before your custom javascript code.

Comment: It is in the same file within the head tags.

Comment: Have you by some chance wrapped this `CallWM` function in a `$(document).ready` event?

Comment: no i havent, should i?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. Could you please show your full code of the WebForm? It looks like your page method is defined on the `Default.aspx` and not on `Register.aspx`.